# My Git repository is in the wrong root directory. Can I move it? (../ instead of ./)

Tags: git

Somehow when I `git init`ed my latest project a month or so ago I ran the command in the directory one directory higher than the root of my project.

So my repository is in the `./project` directory and not the `./project/my-new-project` directory.  I don't know how I didn't realize the issue earlier, but I just never looked for the .git directory until now.

Is there a way, without killing my project, to move the repository to the proper directory and then tell git what the new base of the project is?  Just moving the directory doesn't work.  Git thinks all files have been deleted.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Probably the simplest thing, unless you have already created some history you want to save, would be to just delete the `.git` subdirectory and redo the init in the correct directory.

If you used git to solve the problem, any solution would necessarily leave behind a lot of "moved this file here" history entries that aren't actually changes, but you fixing a screwup at creation time. Better to just create it right.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking.  It wouldn't be a huge loss to lose that history, but it would be nice not to if the fix was relatively easy.

Comment: This breaks a lot of stuff. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3247756/825364 is a much better way to do it.

Comment: Well, saving some history is what Git is used for. Maybe we should just delete the .git subdirectory and uninstall Git from our system? Using an ftp-server instead of vcs is probably the simplest thing after all!

Comment: the answer below is a much better approach since it retains all the history

Comment: So for me, I did this and immediately realized my mistake.  without having any changes to worry about, this is the easiest way to get back to a clean slate.

Answer (score 291):

I had the opposite problem - had to shift the git root to the parent directory (from project/src to project)
To my extreme surprise, the following worked!!

```
src$ mv .git ../ 
src$ cd ..
project$ git add src
project$ git commit -a
```

git cleverly detected that all the new files were renamed versions of old ones and no history was lost

You can try something similar... move the .git folder and add the files again before committing

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I also moved other .git* config files from the directory like .gitigore

Comment: My dear sir, you're a life saviour. This thing really WORKS. Thank you.

Comment: Additionally, I `git rm'd` the files from their old location, so `git status` (correctly) ended up reporting a number of rename operations. The more I work with git, the more I like it.

Comment: @Mike this should be marked as the accepted answer. It's a preferred solution to re-initing because you don't lose history. If you don't believe me, the upvote count speaks for itself.

Comment: the history is kept but not cleanly

Comment: @AlexR : are you refering to the fact that the old commits still reference old paths of the moved files?

Comment: I'm using Git 1.9.1 which I think is the default for Ubuntu 14.04. I do not get renames. After mv .git ../../../.. and git add src/com/domain/package I see only deleted .java files and new .java files.

Comment: @H2ONaCl Can you try a very small moving example on a toy repo, and post all the steps (preferably command-line) to reproduce the problem? You should also include the steps for creation of the toy repo.

Comment: @AbhishekAnand After doing your method, how can you later checkout to a earlier version of the program?  If I do every file is moved/appears where the .git is now.

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me, but I had to do a couple more things:
1. Before committing, I updated `.gitignore` and ran `git add -A` in the root folder; after this, git correctly showed all files as `renamed` rather than `deleted`.
2. Since I use submodules, I had to move `.gitmodules` to the new root, and update the submodule path in the various git configuration files. To find which files to modify I ran `grep -nrI --color 'old/path/to/submodule' . `

Comment: While it is true to correctly create git the first time (as explained by @T.E.D), we do not always have this luxury. With that said @AbhishekAnand answer is most correct.

Answer (score 47):

This worked for me, and kept all my history intact. From the incorrect root folder (the parent where you accidentally initialized the repo):

Move the folder:

```
mv .git thecorrectfolder/
```

Re-initialize the git repo:

```
cd thecorrectfolder/
git init
```

Re-add all the files, commit, and push:

```
git add .
git commit -am 'fixing things'
git push origin master
```

Done! Get yourself a beer.

When you commit the git repo after re-initializing, you'll get a bunch of output that looks like this:

```
rename {ethanode/coffee => coffee}/app.coffee (100%)
```

In other words, all of your references from the parent folder and being renamed to use the correct folder.

Comment: This worked for me, but it was slightly ugly. As far as git's concerned, I didn't 'move' anything, I just deleted hundreds of files and then added hundreds of other, identical files.

Comment: git init is not required and the remaining part is same as my answer which was submitted years before yours: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3247756/391753

Answer (score 34):

`git filter-branch` lets you rewrite history in that way. The [`git filter-branch` man page](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) even has your case [as an example](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html#_examples):

> To rewrite the repository to look as if foodir/ had been its project root,
>   and discard all other history:
>
> ```
> git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter foodir -- --all
> ```

You probably want to `git clone` the repo into a new subdirectory before (or after?) the `git filter-branch` run. (Cloning before filter-branch and running the filter-branch on the new clone would have the advantage of leaving the original `.git/` dir in place as a backup in case something goes wrong.)

Comment: This doesn't "discard all other ***history***" (suggesting the `.git` repo stays at top level while subdirectories become "thought of as the root") - this will literally discard all other files in the repo, and move all `subdirectory/*` files up to the root folder.

Comment: Great answer, but keep in mind that if there's a .gitignore file (if tracked), it will be lost with this operation. Also, you'll need to do a `git push --force` to update the upstream repository after this.

Answer (score 15):

Git can remember files with their hashes,

Just move your `.git` to root directory and tell `git` to remember all files changes with `--all` option.

```
$ mv .git ../
$ cd ..
$ git add . --all 
$ git status // => you can see all the files recognized as renamed 100%
$ git commit -m "Moves repo to root directory."
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `git-mv` to move your files "up" to the proper location, then `git-rm` the "my-new-project" directory.

Comment: It's the other way around.  I don't want to move all my files down to the directory git is in (there's tons of other stuff there...it'd be annoying) and then move git up.  I want to move the repository up to the root directory of my project.

Answer (score 2):

I came here looking for a way to move my repository *anywhere*.

In case, I was not the only one, here's what I did in the end:

https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#How_do_I_clone_a_repository_with_all_remotely_tracked_branches.3F
I "git clone --mirror"d a bare copy of my repo and afterwards told it to not be bare anymore, so the files showed up in that new folder. (Then checked whether or not files and log had appeared.) Kept the old repo for a while, just in case...

That way I was able to move my repo without losing history.

Best Greetings,
Dinah

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it appears that you could have achieved that by simply moving the repository directory to its designated position using nothing but bare filesystem tools, like `mv /path/to/the/old/location/of/the/repo /path/to/the/new/location/of/the/repo`.

Answer (score 2):

Having just gone through this same problem my eventual solution was:

1. Move the .git folder to where it needed to be.
2. Change directory to the folder that I have just moved .git to
3. Reset the folder contents to what git thinks that it should be: `git reset --hard HEAD`
4. Check that the contents match what they should be with kdiff3 or another compare tool
5. Delete the now un-versioned files at the old location.

It worked like magic with no impact on the history. - **N.B.** If you have made some changes be sure to commit them before the move of the .git directory.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in my case is to use git filter-repo. Only 1 command to get the job done.

so you have a directory structure like this
/var/www/html/templates
/var/www/html/templates/.git

you want to move your git repro to
/var/www/html/.git

Before proceeding [install git-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/tree/main#how-do-i-install-it)

if you are still testing and playing around and don't want your current repo to be corrupted do:

```
git remote -v
```

and configure something new here assuming Github

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/***.git
```

now the magic

```
cd /var/www/html/templates
git filter-repo --to-subdirectory-filter templates --force
```

this will give an output like:

Parsed 112 commits
New history written in 2.46 seconds; now repacking/cleaning...
Repacking your repo and cleaning out old unneeded objects
Updating files: 100% (648/648), done.
HEAD is now at 5b40a5d delete obsolete pages2pdf files
Enumerating objects: 973, done.
Counting objects: 100% (973/973), done.
Delta compression using up to 20 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (600/600), done.
Writing objects: 100% (973/973), done.
Total 973 (delta 458), reused 726 (delta 259), pack-reused 0
Removing duplicate objects: 100% (256/256), done.
Completely finished after 28.93 seconds.

Now move your .git directory to /var/www/html/ and move the files in the templates directory to the new templates directory.

Commit and the result is you have changed your git directory and preserved the history.

For more info check you the [filter-repo documentation](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html)

Answer (score -3):

There are two ways here:

> 1. cd TheWrongDirectory    rm -rf .git
> 2. just DELETE the .git folder and     cd to the right directory.