# Github Showing Parent Directories

Tags: github, tree, project

I have a website I'm developing, it's github is https://github.com/samclark2015/Project-Emerald. I have the repo under my user folder in a subdirectory. Now when I push the site to github, it updates the tree as Sites/Project Emerald/... I need the contents of the project emerald folder in the root of my github repo. How can I change the root of my repo on my PC?

Answer (score 0):

Since you just did your first commit in your GitHub repo, the easiest way would be to:

- delete your local `.git` directory you have under '`Site`'
- recreate your repo locally, and force push it:

That would give:

```
# in Site/Project-Emerald
git init . 
git add remote origin https://samclark2015@github.com/samclark2015/Project-Emerald.git
git add .
git commit -m "first commit, again"
git push -force origin master
```

You would then see in your GitHub repo directly:

```
PHP     
SpryAssets  
pictures    
README  
config.inc
...
```

Other alternatives are mentioned in "[My Git repository is in the wrong root directory. Can I move it? (`../` instead of `./`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918111/my-git-repository-is-in-the-wrong-root-directory-can-i-move-it-intead-of)"