# How to move where git looks for the repository

Tags: git

So I’ve installed git on my Linux machine, and tried to play with it on my local computer.
The problem is that since the *.git* folder was generated in the *home* folder, every time I type *"git status"* it prints all the folders in the *home* folder as untracked files.

I tried to move the *.git* folder, but then git can't find it.
So my question is, is it possible to change where git looks and generate my repository?

Thanks.

Comment: Git always works relative to the folder you're in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not initialize a repo in `/home`, if you do that, it means that the repo is in your home directory, here is a example:
[image]

As you can see, I `git init` a repo in my home directory, and all my files in my home directory belong to this repo I initialized just now.

SO,if you want to initialize a repo, you should `mkdir your_repo_directory` in you `/home` directory or other directory.

And if you want to remove the `.git` file, just `rm -rf .git`

On my machine, I remove the `.git` file
[image]

And you can see there is no git repo in `/home`

If you have more question about remove the `.git` file. You can click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918111/my-git-repository-is-in-the-wrong-root-directory-can-i-move-it-instead-of/31719166#31719166)

Answer (score 0):

Judging by what you're asking, you may have initialized an empty repository in your home directory. If you didn't want to do that, then removing .git will remove the repo.

Comment: But how then I initialize the new repository in a different path?

Comment: Go to the path you want to initialize it in and type `git init` and that will initialize a new repository in that directory.