# How do I move the .git folder to a parent folder without losing history?

Tags: git

My local git repository looks like this

```
C:\MyRepo
      \MyProject
           \.git
           \ProjectFolder1
           \ProjectFolder2
           \ProjectFolder3
```

Now I want to add few folders which needs to be directly under "MyRepo" and needs to be part of same repository. I guess that means .git folder should also go directly under "MyRepo"

```
C:\MyRepo
     \.git
     \NewFolder1
     \NewFolder2
     \MyProject
           \ProjectFolder1
           \ProjectFolder2
           \ProjectFolder3
```

How do I move the .git folder up a level **without** losing the history?

I'm using Windows OS and git version is 2.6.3.windows.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Git repository is in the wrong root directory. Can I move it? (../ instead of ./)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918111/my-git-repository-is-in-the-wrong-root-directory-can-i-move-it-instead-of)

Answer (score 6):

You can move all your files to an inner `MyProject` folder before moving the git repo. Something like this might work:

```
cd C:\MyRepo\MyProject
mkdir MyProject
git mv -k * MyProject
git commit
move .git ..
cd MyProject
move * ..
cd ..
rmdir MyProject
cd ..
git add NewFolder1 NewFolder2
git commit
```

See also [How to import existing Git repository into another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683531/how-to-import-existing-git-repository-into-another)

Comment: I like the `-k` flag. I didn't know it.

Comment: @AtnNn I cut and pasted .git folder from “C:\MyRepo\MyProject\.git” to “C:\MyRepo”. Then from the command prompt “C:\MyRepo” i executed “git add *” and then “git commit” to commit changes locally. Then add new folders under “MyRepo” and executed add and commit again.  That seems to working. Is there anything wrong with this process

Comment: @AtnNn Also when i run first 2 of your commands, which creates a new folder and then i check git status..it says "on branch master. nothing to commit, working directory clean"

Comment: @user3862378 What you did might just work. If `git status` doesn't complain and your history is preserved, you should be fine. Perhaps my instructions are wrong. I tested them in bash and translated them for windows.

Answer (score 0):

The important bit to consider is that the name of the parent folder of a repo is irrelevant to the repo.

1. rename "MyRepo/MyProject" to "MyRepo/tmp"
2. create a new folder "MyRepo/tmp/MyProject"
3. move all (except ".git") from "MyRepo/tmp" to "MyRepo/tmp/MyProject"
4. commit -m "Move everything to MyProject"
5. move all (including ".git") from "MyRepo/tmp" to "MyRepo"
6. remove "MyRepo/tmp"