# Git rebase/merge branch with many moved files and folders

Tags: git

I have a Git repository with two main branches: master and dev. It currently looks like this:

```
master  ( )----( )----(A)----(B)----(C)
                \
                 \
dev              ( )----( )----( )----( )----(~ 30 additional commits...)
```

Pretty simple, except that commit **A** on master contains a major change to the file and folder structure (basically, I used [the steps shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3247756/19036) to move the repository up one level in the hierarchy).

I would like to resume work on the dev branch, but when I tried to rebase dev onto master to bring the new file structure into dev, Git spewed a ton of errors. I `git reset` my way back to a sane state, but in my (somewhat limited) experience with Git, that many errors usually means that I was taking the wrong approach.

Is there a better way to get the reorganized folder structure over to the dev branch? If it helps, the changes in the other commits on master (**B** and **C**) are pretty minor and I would be OK with losing them if it would make things easier.

Comment: I haven't actually *tried* this, but if your Git is new enough, `rebase` now has `-s <strategy>` and `-X <strategy-option>`, so you can add `-X find-renames=<n>` to force rebase to use a merge style cherry pick with a particular rename detection threshold, or simply `git rebase -m` to force it to use merge-enabled cherry-picking in the first place (though whether you're getting that now is also Git version-dependent, as well as rebase-command dependent). Since you're getting into Git minutiae, you may want to include exact commands used.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, there is a sane way to do this.

## Preface

`master` is now (if I understood correctly):

```
project
   src
     file.c
```

`dev` is, since it did not contain commit `A`:

```
src
  file.c         # with some changes
```

Your branches are like this:

```
master  ( )----(A0)----(A)----(B)----(C)
                \
                 \
dev              (D1)----(D2)----(D3)----( )----(~ 30 additional commits...)
```

I also assume that `A` differs from `A0` in no way whatsoever, except `project/` being inserted into all file paths ("moving your tree up" into the new `project` root, as per your linked question).

## Let's do it...

We do exactly what `git rebase` would do internally, while fooling `git` a bit, on every step, by doing our own "cherry-pick" step instead of what `git` would do itself.

We use a second working directory. `$WD1` is the absolute path to your original working directory, `$WD2` is some other absolute path (outside of that).

First, create your helper directory as a clone of your original:

```
cd $WD2
git clone $WD1 dev .
```

Then, start a branch `newdev` which will eventually be `dev` rebased on `A`.

```
cd $WD1
git checkout A
git checkout -b newdev
```

We get the `D1` commit into `newdev` without giving `git` any chance to mess it up:

```
cd $WD2
git checkout D1

cd $WD1
rm -r project/src
cp -r $WD2/src project/
git add -A
git commit -m "`cd $WD2 ; git log -1 --format=%s`"
```

The situation is now:

```
newdev                       (D1')     
                           /
                         /
master  ( )----(A0)----(A)----(B)----(C)
                \
                 \
dev              (D1)----(D2)----(D3)----( )----(~ 30 additional commits...)
```

Now, repeat for `D2`:

```
cd $WD2
git checkout D2

cd $WD1
rm -r project/src
cp -r $WD2/src project/
git add -A
git commit -m "`cd $WD2 ; git log -1 --format=%s`"
```

The situation is now:

```
newdev                       (D1')----(D2')     
                           /
                         /
master  ( )----(A0)----(A)----(B)----(C)
                \
                 \
dev              (D1)----(D2)----(D3)----( )----(~ 30 additional commits...)
```

Repeat until finished.

Of course, you will want to create a small shell script for those commands, which iterates through all commits `D1 ... D30`.

Afterwards, a simple `git rebase master` will do the rebase from `A` to `C` as usual. Then, get rid of `newdev` by changing the name around:

```
git checkout newdev
git branch olddev dev         # just in case...
git branch -D dev
git checkout -b dev
```

## General notes

Why the second working directory?

Note that in this particular case there might be ways to avoid the secondary working directory, by using `rm -r project/src ; git checkout D1 src ; mv src project/` directly. I prefer to do it as shown above instead, just to be 100% sure everything is very clean and "visible" at all times. This way the checkout operation is cleanly separated from the modification that we apply on our own.

There is literally nothing that could go wrong this way, and the approach works with all other kinds of changes as well. For a non-trivial change, assume somebody changed every whitespace in every single source file in `A`. This approach makes it trivial to rebase other branches onto this (if you can put that whitespace change into a script as well).

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough solution. This got me pointed in the right direction: cloning the repo into a second folder then looping through the commits on dev and manually "replaying" them on top of master. I used a diff tool to apply the changes in each commit from dev (instead of rm and cp), but it worked!

Comment: Good job, "get'er done", it's the idea that counts. :)

Comment: This answer deserves way more up votes for being so thorough.  Thanks.